# Memory Problem: Average-Linkage Clustering

Tags: r, out-of-memory, bigdata, cluster-analysis, euclidean-distance

Data with a million rows and 18 columns need to be clustered using Average-Linkage Clustering, which in turn requires calculating the Euclidian distance between rows. While doing so, `d <-dist(data)`, R gives the following error:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 3725.3 Gb

My computer has a memory of 32 Gb. What should be my approach?

Answer (score 0):

The distance matrix, even only its upper diagonal, will always need about 2TB of memory. Moreover, a fast implementation of hierarchical clustering has time complexity $O(n^2)$. You can try two things:

1. Use the function `hclust.vector` from the fastcluster package, which does not require a distance matrix as input and thereby saves space complexity at the expense of time complexity.
2. Use a different clustering algorithm that is not based on all pairwise distances, e.g. k-means.

You can also try s hybrid approach by first condensing the data with 2. and then applying 1.